# RelativeLayout center vertical 3 textviews

Tags: android, xamarin

I'm trying to reduce the number of hierarchies on my list item so I have only one RelativeLayout, but I'm struggling to understand how can I do the same behave of a LinearLayout.

For example:

```
  <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/ordercardcontentrow"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    local:MvxBind="BackgroundColor NativeColor(BackgroundColour)"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/order_classification_image"
        android:id="@+id/order_header"
        style="@style/NormalText.Regular"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_small"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:singleLine="true"
        local:MvxBind="Text OrderHeader" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/order_classification_image"
        android:id="@+id/post_code"
        android:layout_below="@id/order_header"
        style="@style/TitleText.Regular"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_vlarge"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:singleLine="true"
        local:MvxBind="Text Postcode; Visible IsDelivery" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/order_classification_image"
        android:id="@+id/order_id"
        style="@style/NormalText.Medium"
        android:layout_below="@id/post_code"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_vsmall"
        android:textColor="@color/dark_grey"
        local:MvxBind="Text FormattedOrderId" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

But if the middle one is not visible of course the are not going to be vertically centred in my relative layout, how can I make this happen?

Cheers!

Comment: Can you please post screenshot ..what you want from linear layout ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try that (adapt it to your needs):

remember, android:layout_width and height are mandatory.

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/ordercardcontentrow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="1dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/order_header"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:text="AAAA" />

        <TextView
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:id="@+id/post_code"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/order_header"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:text="BBBB" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/order_id"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/post_code"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:text="CCCC"

            />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use gravity center `android:gravity="center"` for relativelayout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ordercardcontentrow"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
    android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/order_header"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:text="sdff" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/post_code"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/order_header"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:text="sdff" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/order_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/post_code"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:text="sdff" />
</RelativeLayout>
```